# Averaging XML values in Postgres

Tags: xml, postgresql, xpath

I was wondering if anyone could give me an example of averaging XML values in Postgresql? My XML has a structure of `<game><price>12</price></game>` and have used `xpath('//price')` to pull the values but I cannot seem to be able to come up with a query to average the values.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this table structure ...

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_xml (game XML);
INSERT INTO tmp_xml (game) VALUES ('<game><price>12</price></game>'::XML);
INSERT INTO tmp_xml (game) VALUES ('<game><price>11</price></game>'::XML);
INSERT INTO tmp_xml (game) VALUES ('<game><price>13</price></game>'::XML);
```

... you can get the avg from price like this:

```
SELECT AVG((XPATH('//price/text()', game))[1]::TEXT::NUMERIC) FROM tmp_xml;
```